# How to get return value from Popup in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, popup

I have a question about Popup in Blackberry. 
In my application , I have mobile phone list on main screen. And When i click "add" button , i will show popup (by pushScreen popup) that allow input mobile number , and then I click "Ok" close popup ( by popScreen popup) the current list displaying must be updated.

I don't know , how to get return value from Popup. In this case, return value is mobile number input on popup. When popup is closed , list of mobile phone must be refreshed.

Please help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get value from the UI Fields used in a Popup, we have to store the values in some variable and need to implement some getter method. Below is an example of a search popup screen where upon the click on search button, we get the search key entered on the popup screen via a getter method.

**Popup implementation:**

```
class SearchDialog extends Dialog {
    public static final int CANCEL = 1000;
    public static final int SEARCH = 2000;

    private static final String[] choices = { "Search", "Cancel" };
    private static final int[] values = { SEARCH, CANCEL };

    private EditField searchField = new EditField("Address: ", "", 50, EditField.EDITABLE);

    private static Bitmap bmSearch = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("cmd_search.png");

    private SeparatorField separatorField = new SeparatorField(USE_ALL_WIDTH);

    public SearchDialog() {
        super("Search Address", choices, values, SEARCH, bmSearch);

        Manager delegate = getDelegate();
        if (delegate instanceof DialogFieldManager) {
            DialogFieldManager dfm = (DialogFieldManager) delegate;

            Manager manager = dfm.getCustomManager();
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.insert(separatorField, 0);
                manager.insert(new LabelField(), 1);
                manager.insert(searchField, 2);
                manager.insert(new LabelField(), 3);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getSearchKey() {
        return (searchField == null) ? "" : searchField.getText();
    }
}
```

**Getting value from the dialog (search key):**

```
SearchDialog seaerchDialog = new SearchDialog();
int ret = seaerchDialog.doModal();
if (SearchDialog.SEARCH == ret) {
    // get the search key entered on search dialog
    String key = seaerchDialog.getSearchKey();
}
else if (SearchDialog.CANCEL == ret) {
    // do something..
}
```

Comment: Sorry, because i have just tried it but can't refresh main screen, so can't get return value :(

Comment: "I don't know , how to get return value from Popup." -- above code snippet will help you to get data from popup (dialog), but refreshing the screen with new data is simpler. Update the content of your list with the new value and then call invalidate() of the MainScreen. Second problem have several solutions. So keep trying :)